# Cannot connect to Internet after add whitelist using iptables

Tags: iptables

I want to only allow connection from my workstation,

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/8 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -s X.X.X.X -j ACCEPT  # my workstation's public IP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

and it really works. But I find that I cannot connect to outside internet anymore. ( I want to access outside internet with no restricts )

What's wrong? How to fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iptables INPUT rules drop all incoming packages even those that belong to established connections you initiated to the outside - you have to use

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

in addition to your rules so that response packages belonging to outgoing connections are allowed to come back.